# add links to list of post terms

Tags: terms, list

How do I change the function below so that it outputs a list if links rather than a string? The resulting html I need is `<a href="#">term</a> <a href="#">term</a> <a href="#">term</a>` etc.

```
function my_post_term_links() {

// Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

// Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
if ( $taxonomies ) {    

    // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
    $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    // Convert the terms array to a string
    $terms_links = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

    if (!filter_var($terms_links , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
       $terms_links ="<a href='#'>".$terms_links."</a>";
    }  

    // Get out of here
    return $terms_links;
}
}
```

UPDATE//

I managed to get the function to display and list of terms with links as required by adding a for loop but it duplicates teh last terms and adds it on the end without a link...

```
    foreach ( $arr_terms  as $terms_links ) {
        echo '<a href="#">' . $terms_links . '</a>';
    }
```

So this is how the function looks now...

```
function my_post_term_links() {

// Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

// Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
if ( $taxonomies ) {    

    // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
    $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    // Convert the terms array to a string
    //$terms_links = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

    foreach ( $arr_terms as $terms_links ) {
        if(!empty($terms_links)) {
        echo '<a href="#">' . $terms_links . '</a>';
        }
    }

    /*if (!filter_var($terms_links , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
       $terms_links ="<a href='#'>".$terms_links."</a>";
    }  */

    // Get out of here
    return $terms_links;
}
}
```

Comment: And what is the current output?

Comment: the current output is a string e.g. `term term term`

Comment: a string of terms without links that is, and i need the links to have hashtags in as above.

Comment: I've nearly got it!! I updated the the post above please see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try to add

```
foreach ( $arr_terms  as $terms_links ) {
    if(!empty($terms_links)) {
    echo '<a href="#">' . $terms_links . '</a>';
    }
}
```

That checks if the `$terms_links` is empty, and if so it wont print it out.

Comment: That didn't work, same ouput.

Comment: What exactly is your HTML output, can you post it here?

Comment: `<a href="#">term</a><a href="#">term</a><a href="#">term</a><a href="#">term</a><a href="#">term</a>term`

Comment: just amended the post showing how the function looks now

Comment: Try to comment out the "return $terms_links;" maybe that is the problem.